# SSRS Azure SQL Database Active Directory - Universal with MFA

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, azure-sql-database, authentication, active-directory

Does anyone know when support for [Active Directory - Universal with MFA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-ssms-mfa-authentication) will be included in Reporting Services?

It's available in SSMS.

Visual Studio 2017 Data Source Properties

[image: SSRS data source Properties]

Reporting Server Data Source Properties

[image: Reporting Server Data Source Properties]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MFA auth flow is interactive.  For me, for instance, it opens a browser window, displays an code, and I get a notification on my phone to approve the login.

So you can't use it in background services like SSRS.

Answer (score -1):

Use OLEDB connector and type the connection string directly:

```
Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;User ID=myUserName;Use Encryption for Data=true;
```

Comment: SQL supports several authentication methods, one of which is called "Active Directory - Universal with MFA". Your answer recommends using a different authentication method, "Active Directory Interactive". Your answer does not address the question asked.